# Laravel pagination: less items on first page only?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6's simple pagination that simply display 25 items per page.

However, I need to update this code to display 40 items on page 2 and up. And still keeping 25 items on the first page.

This is my current laravel eloquent query in the controller.

```php
$items = Item::where('active',1)
    ->with(['location', 'spec'])
    ->orderBy('id','ASC')
    ->paginate(25);
```

View (Added after @mare96 's comment)

```php
@foreach($items as $item)
  ID: {{$item->id}}<br>
  Name: {{$item->name}}<br>
  Description: {{$item->description}}<br>
@endforeach
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide code from your view? You can send information from your view for example `$per_page` and when you need more you can just send as value. If you want to provide code I ll show you how you can do that. Good luck.

Comment: @mare96 I've updated the view code into the post. However, I would prefer to do the said pagination on the Controller level, because I did update all fetched records (eg: page views) right after the query.